# How to make an ImageView overlay another View and hide it after a certain period of time?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, delay

I'm making a very simple Andriod app and I was wondering if I could get some help with my app.

I would like to show an ImageView over the full ListView (including the action bar) for 3 seconds, and then remove the ImageView (or hide it, anything), to go back to the list view.

How can this be done? I have tried a few things but it either breaks my code or doesn't show anything at all.

Thanks in advance everyone - let me know if you need any further explanation.

EDIT: As per the question below, I'd like the ImageView to be shown as soon as the ListView is shown, for 3 seconds, then disappear.

Comment: Do you want this behaviour when an list item is clicked?

Comment: No, sorry, I'll edit my question explain. I would like this to be shown as soon as the ListView is shown, for 3 seconds, then to disappear.

Comment: google "show splash screen android"

Comment: I already have a splash screen implemented - this isn't what I want. My image is transparent and I would like the list view to be shown beneath.

Comment: create custom dialog and, show it and put one timer with 3000 ms delay and dismiss dialog from the timer

Comment: u need popup to display the image over there, for 3secs?

Comment: Can a custom dialog be fullscreen? This was one of the first things I thought about but from reading about it, it's more for prompts and additional information for the user.

Comment: Yes, I want an image to "pop up" for 3 seconds, over my list view.

Comment: I answered your question to show how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright. What you want is actually quite easy.

Simply **create a RelativeLayout that contains a ListView and an ImageView above it.**
Then inside your onCreate(...) method, you **use a Handler** and set the Visibility of the ImageView to **GONE** after 3 seconds.

Here is the layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And **inside the onCreate(...)** method:

```
@Override    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // EITHER HIDE IT IMMEDIATELY
            iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // OR HIDE IT USING ANIMATION
            hideImageAnimated(iv);

            // DONT use both lines at the same time :)
        }
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds
}
```

In order to make things a bit **smoother**, you could use an **AlphaAnimation** on your ImageView:

```
public void hideImageAnimated(final ImageView iv) {

    Animation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    alpha.setDuration(1000); // whatever duration you want

    // add AnimationListener
    alpha.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }

    });

    iv.startAnimation(alpha);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. Some follow up questions - any way for the image to fade out? And also, the image looks quite stretched. Should I change the image dimensions, or is there a way to set the size with the XML (without it look odd!)?

Comment: Take a look at the different "scale-types" that can be used for ImageView in .xml.
If you want the ImageView to always cover full screen, then you probably need to use a different scale type than I did above or change the image dimenstions to fit the screen properly.
I will update my question to show you how to animate the ImageView properly.